# not able to dynamically call a class

Tags: php, oop

i am trying to dynamically **call** a class in php but each time i try i get an error message telling me that the class cannot be found

**this is my class factory (i am using the factory method to dynmically create classes on the fly):**

```
class EmailFactory 
{
  public function build ($class)  
 {
   return new $class();
  }

}
```

**the error message:** 
this is the error I get when i tried calling the class

> Fatal error: Class 'ProfileApproved' not found

**Instantiating and Calling the Class**
this is how i called the class:

```
 $this->emailClass = (new EmailFactory)->build("ProfileApproved");
```

the class can be found because when i do this, the system is able to render the class:

```
class EmailFactory 
    {
      public function build ($class)  
     {
       return new ProfileApproved();
      }

    }
```

i am using php 5.5.12

so, i should be able to render the class.

appreciate any advice the way i did

**CLAIRIFCATION**

I forgot to mention that i did include the name of the class at the top of the page: i.e

```
include_once('ProfileApproved.php');
```

**here is my ProfileApproved Class**

Below is my ProfileApproved class. there is nothing speical about the class, no constructors. it just rendered HTML email.

so, there is no reason why it should not be rendered dynamically.

```
namespace ConversionEmails\Services\Employer\Emails;

use ConversionEmails\Services\ConversionEmails as Emails;

class ProfileApproved  implements Emails
{

    public function getHtmlEmail($params)
    {      
        return "test works";
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your ProfileApporved class is defined/declared? If it is not in the same file then use autoload to include it properly while instantiating..

Comment: hi. ProfileApporved is in the same directory. i have also tried using autoloader but it makes no difference, still does not work

Comment: are you using namespaces ?

Comment: yes. i am using namespaces. i am actually using a framework. zend 2

Comment: it might be in same directory. But have you included that file in a calling place?

Comment: Hi Vinoth. i did indeed include it: include_once('ProfileApproved.php');

Comment: You are using namespaces. Can you try calling the string version with its full namespace? Your example using a regular new ProfileApproved will automatically import the proper namespace, but dynamic casting cannot do this and will need the full namespace provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you included the class's file?

```
<?php

namespace EXAMPLE;

class Calling
{
    public function build( $ns, $name )
    {
        $name = $ns . $name;
        if( !class_exists ( $name ) )
        {
            echo 'The class doesn\'t exist' . PHP_EOL;
            return;
        }

        return new $name();
    }
}

class Called
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo 'Works for me' . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

$var = ( new Calling )->build( '\\EXAMPLE\\', 'Called' );
```

That works perfectly fine for me.

Edit : Try calling class_exists (http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php) before trying to instantiate the class.

Edit : I changed my code to use namespaces.

Comment: hi James. yes. i have indeed included the file names. i have tried everything. i have even tried using the does the class_exists() function. i am extremely baffled by it. the code you pasted here is exactly similar to my code. so, i dont understand why it does not work

Comment: Could you post the ProfileApproved code? Is there any specific constructor requirements, etc?

Comment: hi James. i will add the ProfileApproved Class now

Comment: wow. james. thanks a million. you were right. it was the namespace. it was not finding it. i tried your method and it works now. wow. thanks a million for that